# Visibility timeout on AWS SQS Fifo queues with batch size 1

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sqs-fifo

I have an SQS Fifo queue with batch size 1 and visibility timeout configured at 30s.

The lambda function consuming from the queue is configured with a 30s timeout as well.

Any reason in this scenario to follow AWS recommendation to increase the visibility timeout to 6 times the Lambda function timeout?

Comment: Same happening for me. Any luck solving this @x-term

Comment: @DD24 Couldn't find any good reason for increasing the visibility timeout. In my setup, if the message is not successfully processed, it is retried 20 times before being moved to a DLQ (or successfully processed, whichever happens first). That means that during retries, no other messages get processed. Increasing the visibility timeout only increases  the duration of the queue being blocked in my case, so didn't go ahead with the recommendation (btw, it was suggested by Amazon DevOps Guru tool)